# Best Practice for Defining Constant Values in a Java Game

Tags: java, constants

I'm currently working on writing a turn-based strategy game in Java, and I'm at the point were I need to start defining rules and behaviors for some of the game elements. Specifically, each tile on the map is going to have buildings in it. Each turn, each of the buildings is going to produce or consume resources, based on the type of building it is (a lumber mill would consume 1 log and produce 1 lumber, a bakery would consume 1 wheat and produce one bread, etc.). The `Building` class is generic, with a field `buildingType` that denotes what type of building it is, with `BuildingType` being an enum. These rules are going to be the same for each building of the same type (all bakeries will abide by the same rule, etc.) and they will be constant throughout the entire game.

The part I'm having trouble with is where to define these rules. So far, I've come up with three options:

1. Store the types and amount of resources consumed and produced for each building in a file on disk, and read in this file when the game starts up, storing the contents in a map.
2. Create a class that either has all the rules defined as static fields or populates a map with hard-coded rule values, and then have a static method that returns the rule based on the `BuildingType`.
3. Create subclasses of `Building` for each `BuildingType`, and define the rules corresponding to that building type as static fields in each `Building` subclass.

Right now, I'm considering option 2 for a few reasons:

- Disk reads are slow, so defining the constants in a Java class seems like it would make the game load a lot faster.
- Having a separate file on disk could make it easier for pesky users to modify the rules.
- While option 3 seems like the more "Java-ish" approach, each of the `Buildings` will behave the exact same way, just abiding by different rules. So it seems like a lot of overhead to create a bunch of different classes that simply define different constants.
- I'd prefer to have the rules all stored in one central location, rather than spread out in a bunch of different subclasses.
- Having `static final` constants in option 2 seems like it would be the best way to ensure the rules are read-only.

My question is, what is the standard convention for storing constant rules in a game? Is there any advantage of choosing options 1 or 3 that I missed? And is there any downside, other than ending up with a really long java file, with option 2 that I'm not seeing?

Comment: 'Disk reads are slow" - who cares if you read them on startup and cache them?  If they have to change, externalize them.  If not, make them static.  A single class just for constants would make me a little ill.

Comment: I think you should try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).